# IE 11 not remembering login from 1st tab to the 2nd tab in same IE Session

Tags: authentication, tabs, internet-explorer-11

I've had an issue for a while, where my IE 11 does not remember the login for a site from 1 tab to the next.

I can login to a site with no issue, but if I click a link & want to open it into a new tab (within the same IE window) the new tab will show that I'm no longer logged into that site.

The same thing applies to when I'm placing an order online & if I open a new tab from that same site, then the items which were in my cart, no longer exist.

NOTE: I wanted to post 2 screenshots I had, but the site won't let me post those, let me know how I can those to someone if want to see them.

I have tried a few things relating to changing settings in IE, one was from this site & the other from Microsoft & a couple of others from other sites.

NOTE - site won't allow me to post more then 1 link, if you need more info, let me know how I can get it to you.

[IE11 does not send session cookie when a link targeting a new tab is clicked (on first request)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031602/ie11-does-not-send-session-cookie-when-a-link-targeting-a-new-tab-is-clicked-on)

None of these of these has worked & I haven't seen the question asked specifically the way I've posed it.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed similar behavior is triggered when X-UA-Compatible changes mode between pages, especially when the session starts with IE=edge and gets switched to IE=7 on a later page.  It seems session cookies are lost in the new IE PID started up for the IE 7 compatibility mode page.  Does that happen to apply at all to your situation?